# Is it possible to place one view over another in android?

Tags: android, view, android-videoview, overlapping

Can we place a small view over another large view? For example, I have a VideoView which is playing a file in the background. Over this, somewhere in the middle/corner, I want to place another ImageView.

But in Linear/Relative Layout, views can be placed only one after another or relative to each other, and AbsoluteLayout is advised against. So what do I do?

Comment: RelativeLayout will work but you can use FrameLayout.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`FrameLayouts` let you pile each view on top of the one below. This can also be achieved with a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of either case? I am not able to think it out.

Comment: @kiki - Google "android FrameLayout" and you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690530/how-to-show-one-layout-on-top-of-the-other-programmatically-in-my-case

Comment: Use FrameLayout as it allow you to overlapping between views

Answer (score 65):

The `FrameLayout` is the simplest `ViewGroup` and stacks the `Views` in the order they're defined in layout XML (or added programmatically); the first will be lower, and the last will be on top.

Here is an example where two `Views` are stacked and offset to better illustrate the point:

[image]

Here is the actual layout XML with the two overlapping `TextView` boxes.  The offset of the two boxes is done using `android:layout_gravity` while `android:gravity` is used for centering the text itself within each box.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="First is below"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=" Last is on top"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Comment: This answer is pure gold!

Comment: It doesn't work. can't drag the element over the bottom element in design view.

Answer (score 37):

Just in case if you want to place a view on top of a ButtonView then use this;
`android:elevation="7dp"` for the view which needs to be placed on top of the button.

Comment: Thanks. It worked, but also worked with 1dp up for me.

Comment: Thanks , I got stuck to send back the button for hours.You saved my day

Answer (score 5):

You can also do it by using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) a new layout introduced by google.

> ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups).

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_weight="4"
  tools:context="com.edalat.example.MainActivity">
  <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="283dp"
    android:layout_height="349dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.509"/>
  <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: In ConstraintLayout, views are placed taking in consideration the order. For example 
       `<ConstraintLayout> <View1/> <View2/> </ConstraintLayout>`                                  View2 will be placed over View1 (if both are in the same place on screen)

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/dp_20"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    >
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/camera"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create Relative Layout and place views inside it and add

```
android:elevation="2dp"
```

for the view whcich is to be over another one

Comment: If you are using materialCardView Like components then you should use android:cardElevation

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily by putting the back layouts before forwarded layouts in XML file.

for example if I want to `cardView1` comes over `cardView2` I write this code:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Since `cardView2` comes before `cardView1` , `cardView1` is the one that comes over the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Quite the same problem solved. I did it by placing the needed element between two layouts and using negative value for `android:layout_marginTop` attribute.

Here's the code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="-35dp">
```

And how it looks in the layout:

[I'm not allowed to post pictures yet, so here's a link to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOlEo.png)