# Android: Transparent Icon bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, transparent

I'd like to use these transparent icon bars, seen in the screenshot on [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps&hl=en) page. Does anybody know which component this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps uses `ActionBar` with the `FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY` set. In phones, they also enable the split ActionBar.

Comment: Thanks, I think this fits best for my attempts.

Comment: Now I see that it's available from 3.0. Unfortunately I can't develop for 3.0 due to this distribution level (http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), so I will stay with FrameLayout.

Answer (score 1):

They are presumably a `LinearLayout` with a translucent background.

Comment: Thanks, it works with FrameLayout best. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690530/how-to-show-one-layout-on-top-of-the-other-programmatically-in-my-case

Answer (score 0):

Set the background to some color with a mid level alpha.

This one is black with an alpha of 180. The first 2 characters are the alpha in hexadecimal, the other 6 are rgb in hexadecimal.

```
android:background="#B4000000"
```