# Portrait mode and landscape mode views display adjustment with phone size

Tags: android, layout, landscape-portrait

I want to adjust the layouts according to the `Landscape mode` and `portrait mode`.

In my 7' tablet device the `portrait mode` is too small and `Landscape mode` is quite large. Due to small portrait mode, the list items and some text is mixing like button
size got reduced, one text crossed the other one, etc..

So for the same view layout, I want to have different setups according to the modes.

For example consider this SO post of [One Layout over the Top of Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690530/how-to-show-one-layout-on-top-of-the-other-programmatically-in-my-case). I want this scenario for the `portrait mode`. However for the `Landscape mode`, I don't want **overlapping** of one view on top of other. Rather I want one view on one side of the other.

My xml layout file for different modes-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
              android:id="@+id/news_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"              
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
              android:id="@+id/channel_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is this seems good for `landscape mode` but when it comes to portrait mode, I need `news_fragment` to get overlapped over `channel_fragment`.

How to achieve this behavior considering the layout file is same. Or do I have to create new one for portrait too?

Answer (score 2):

You simply create 2 different layout files. You should read the [developer guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on this subject.

Basically you make 2 res/layout folders:
`res/layout` and
`res/layout-land`

Then you add a layout for landscape to the `land` folder and the portrait version to the other.

Comment: Actually I have 2 res/layout files: `res/layout/activity_main` and `res/layout-large/activity_main`. But the former is for tablet device and the latter one is for mobile device. Do I still have to create 2 more - 1 for portrait and 1 for landscape? The above xml in question is for tablet device.

Comment: @SaurabhJain, yes but you can have multiple options at the same time like: res/layout-large-land (there is an order of it, not sure this was the correct, but you can read about it on the developer guides)

Comment: This is quite confusing at first. Do you know what is the name for the layout file in portrait mode for the tablet device Or do you have any documentation to look at? Is it `res/layout-large-port` ?

Comment: @SaurabhJain If you have one for land the regular one will be for port so you don't need to make a folder for port.

Comment: But if I don't make a folder for port then how can I get the one view overlapping the other one affect ? The one for land is having one view after other and is not overlapping. Without making other folder for port Is it possible?

Comment: @SaurabhJain You got res/layout-large-land and res/layout-large. 2 folders. 1, 2 HAHAHAHAA <-- (like the count from sesam street)

Comment: AHA..got it. But me got res/layout/activity_main for mobile device. And res/layout-large/activity_main for both tablet(Portrait and Landscape). So can't distinguish the Portrait with Landscape. What about making res/layout-large-land/activity_main and res/layout-large-port/activity_main to get it distinguished?

Comment: @SaurabhJain you should really go read the link I gave you. Go read the chapter "Using configuration qualifiers" right now, I demand it. Your understanding on this subject will be so much better afterward.

Answer (score 0):

So according to the scenario:

I kept three layout folders viz..

- res/layout/activity_main (for mobile devices)
- res/layout-large/activity_main (for tablet devices with Portrait Mode)
- res/layout-large-land/activity_main (for tablet devices with Landscape Mode)

All the three layout files contains there own containers as needed to display accordingly.

**The trick is:**

Since the activity_main of `layout-large-land` is taking care of Landscape orientation of tablet devices, therefore the activity_main of `layout-large` will by default will be for
portrait mode.

So for mobile devices views, for tablets different orientations--the above scenario is best
and is working great!