# how to put 2 layouts on top of each others

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to put 2 layouts on top of each others but it doesn't work.There is a space that i don't know how to remove.

here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:background="@drawable/column_white"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="vertical"

                    >
                    <LinearLayout 
                        android:layout_width="10sp"
                        android:layout_height="100sp"
                        android:background="@drawable/arrow_body"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                        ></LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout 
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:background="@drawable/arrow_shape"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6sp"
                        ></LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_margin="25sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/column_blue"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="40 000 "
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
```

with `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:background="@drawable/column_white"
        android:gravity="bottom"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/second_part"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="10sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_body" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6sp"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_shape" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/second_part"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="25sp"

        android:background="@drawable/column_blue"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="40 000"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use Relative layout as root view.

Comment: Use RelativeLayout or FrameLayout as root

Comment: i tried that as well, modified my code

Comment: Can you show us screenshot ?

Comment: Read my comment. In your relative layout you still have your margin:25sp in the second one.

Comment: [This answer maybe helpful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6690607/4104167)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Relative layout to place views on top of each other , like this

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                android:background="#37c100" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6sp"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_shape" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="25sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="40 000 "
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your second `LinearLayout`, you have a `android:layout_margin="25sp"`.
Remove this line or at least don't set a marginTop.

Answer (score -1):

This can now also be done using a constraintlayout. In my use case I had a RecyclerView that when empty had to be "covered" by a text and a button to allow users to add items to the list. (Part of the Big Nerd Ranch programming book, challenge 13.3)

Code is as follows (change to your own needs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/no_crimes_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_crimes_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/no_crimes"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/recyclerView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/recyclerView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_crime_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/new_crime"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/recyclerView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/recyclerView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/crime_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You dont explain why this works. To my eyes, the RecyclerView would sit on top of the LinearLayout, because it's later in the hierarchy.