# How to remove a line between tablayout and toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-tablayout

There is a line between tab-layout and toolbar that I can not remove. I set `elevation = 0` for both tab-layout and toolbar but it does not help. **Toolbar** is in main activity and **tab-layout** isin another XML file that is related to a fragment. Each fragment separately, has its own XML that contains separate tabs.

This is the tab-layout in file *one.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/srlRefresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:background="@color/grayBackground"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    app:elevation="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/tab"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab_text"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
    
                </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    
            </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and mainactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            />



        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
            style="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/green"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
             app:elevation="0dp"
           >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/favoriteBtn"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                 android:visibility="invisible" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/lightGray"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_color_selecton"
            app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/bottom_navigation_textappreance"
            app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/bottom_navigation_textappreance"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_color_selecton"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            android:elevation="0dp"
           />


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/dataProgressBar"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/lightGray"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/gray"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/green"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/RobotoTextViewStyle"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
        android:theme="@style/divider"
        />
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

with relative layout instead of frameLayout: it dose not work.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"

             />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
            style="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/green"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
            app:elevation="0dp"
           >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/favoriteBtn"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bookmark_off"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Could you include a picture of this line?

Comment: @GavinWright I add it

Comment: The upper green and the green below, are 2 fragments?

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos yes there in two fragment

Comment: In which tag, do you set them, inside mainactivity.XML?

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos FrameLayout

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on there from that screenshot. Can we see the whole screen?

Comment: So is the upper green the LinearLayout, and the green below the androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar?

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos yes the container id

Comment: @GavinWright i add

Comment: So you want to disappear this little white line between the green fragments?

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to put 2 layouts on top of each others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424443/how-to-put-2-layouts-on-top-of-each-others)

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos as you can see the root layout in main activity is relative and both framelayout and toobar are inside it

Comment: @saraaaa would you consider write it little different?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220694/discussion-between-sara-aaa-and-l-papadopoulos).

Answer (score 0):

I set   app:tabBackground="@color/green" for tablayout and problem is solved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/srlRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:background="@color/grayBackground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                app:tabBackground="@color/green"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/tab"
                android:background="@color/green"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab_text"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```