# How to implement a subtitle in CollapsingToolbarLayout like in the whatsapp

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

[image]

what i wanted to implement is shown on the picture ,the details page subtitle shown as" created by +91 "

currently i am able to implement title only .
this is my code used for creating the title i need to create a sub title too any idea ??

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/event_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:transitionName="event_image"
                  />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_event"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_black" >

                </FrameLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(""); ?

Comment: @Shahzeb yes i have ,according to developer blog we can only set the title by  collapsingToolbar.setTitle("title");  what im asking is  , is there any other way to set the subtitle ?

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the frame layout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ImageView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/golden_gate" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

    android:padding="12dip"

    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"

    android:text="Golden Gate" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Full implementation:
[How to show one layout on top of the other programmatically in my case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690530/how-to-show-one-layout-on-top-of-the-other-programmatically-in-my-case)