# Hide View after View finishes its job Xamarin

Tags: c#, xml, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-view

I am trying this new Konfetti View that shows Confetti on the screen, found here:
https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Konfetti

I want this view to disappear after the Confetti stops falling, however with the code I have currently, the Konfetti View disappears before the Confetti even starts falling.

ConfettiActivity:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using NL.DionSegijn.Konfetti;
using NL.DionSegijn.Konfetti.Models;

namespace ConfettiTest
{
    [Activity(Label = "ConfettiActivity")]
    public class ConfettiActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.confetti_activity);
            KonfettiView konfettiView = (KonfettiView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.viewKonfetti);
            int num = 0;
            while (num != 2)
            {
                if (num == 0)
                {
                    konfettiView
                    .Build()
                    .AddColors(Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Magenta)
                    .SetDirection(0.0, 359.0)
                    .SetSpeed(1f, 5f)
                    .SetFadeOutEnabled(true)
                    .SetTimeToLive(4000L)
                    .AddSizes(new Size(12, 5f))
                    .StreamFor(400, 4000L);
                }
                else if (num == 1)
                {
                    konfettiView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                }
                else
                {
                }
                num++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

confetti_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.KonfettiView
        android:id="@+id/viewKonfetti"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Confetti is finished"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/confettifinished"
        android:textSize="50px"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This answer :https://stackoverflow.com/a/6690607/13370965 won't work, cause in my proper code, I have more than 1 textview.

Another alternative is to put the konfettiView in the background, so you can see the textViews and the confetti at the same time, but I can't figure out how to this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **timer** to only show the view for a certain amount of time.

Could look something like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.confetti_activity);

    KonfettiView konfettiView = (KonfettiView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.viewKonfetti);

    konfettiView
    .Build()
    .AddColors(Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Magenta)
    .SetDirection(0.0, 359.0)
    .SetSpeed(1f, 5f)
    .SetFadeOutEnabled(true)
    .SetTimeToLive(4000L)
    .AddSizes(new Size(12, 5f))
    .StreamFor(400, 4000L);

    //Create and run a timer
    Device.StartTimer (new TimeSpan (0, 0, 5000), () =&gt; //(5000 = 5sec)
    {
       Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() =&gt; 
       {
          //Hide the konfetti
          konfettiView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
       });
       return false;
    });          
}
```

Comment: System.Windows.Forms, does not exist

Comment: and `Tick` does not exist also. any alternatives?

Comment: @dan51 my bad. I never worked with Xamarin myself but I updated the code. Now it should work.

Comment: What does =&gt do?

Comment: This still doesn't work for me, as I cannot access Device

Comment: @dan51 it's used to describe the **"greater than" character** _(>)_ . But I don't know why it is used here. I got the code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms).

Comment: ok, thanks for the help! I'll try to use this to figure it out

Comment: @dan51 add `using Xamarin.Forms;` to your namespaces.

Comment: thanks a ton Ottxr, I edited your code so it works for me! `=&gt` is probably just a German version of `=>` :)