# How to implement key preview popup in custom android keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I'm currently developing a custom andriod keyboard

Sample Image:

[image: my custom keyboard sample image]

The basic structure of my keyboard is based on Microsoft SwiftKey.

I have pretty much finished everything except that I cannot find a way to implement the key preview popup.

For example (Gboard and Microsoft SwiftKey
):

[image: Gboard sample image]
[image: Microsoft SwiftKey sample image]

I have looked at different posts on this implementation but all of them were like at least 5 years old and they were using the `KeyboardView` class, which is now deprecated and I have not used it to create my keyboard. So I tried to implement it by myself.

At first I tried to implement it like Microsoft SwiftKey, and I tried increasing the `Button` height each time when I pressed it but it also increased other `Button`s' heights because they are in the same `LinearLayout` and I have used weight to set their height.

So instead I tried to implement it like Gboard but I can't quite figure out how to show the image or text above the key that the user have pressed. I tried using `ImageView` to show the key preview but I'm not sure how or where to add the view in the layout.

Any help or adivce would be apprecited.

Comment: Unclear if you've seen/tried: [Is it possible to place one view over another in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3821684/295004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution by myself.
Use `PopupWindow`: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/PopupWindow

Create a `PopupWindow` and set its `contentView` with a `TextView`. Then whenever you want to show it call `showAtLocation` and `update` method.

For example:

```
val btn = Button(baseContext)
val popup = PopupWindow()
popup.contentView = TextView(baseContext)
val loc = IntArray(2)
btn.getLocationInWindow(loc)
popup.showAtLocation(btn, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0)
popup.update(loc[0], loc[1]-128, 128, 128, false)
```